# Encrypt Result Set from SQL statement

Tags: encryption, gpg4win

I have a task to run an SQL Statement, generate Result Set, encrypt it using GPG and send to user.
I am using GPG4Win-3.1.15 which contains GPG 2.2.x
It works fine for me BUT my goal is to get encrypted file directly from SQL query.
I don't want first generate Result Set, convert it to .csv and then encrypt.
Could someone advice if it's possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually someone from 'Toad ..' forum replied to this question.
It looks that my task could be implemented by using 'Toad's Automation Engine' by creating a workflow where one of step would  be encryption.